# React, localStorage is not persistent upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm new to React and I can't understand what's wrong with my use of the `useEffect` hook. The code is compiled successfully and everything seems to work. The components added by the user are shown on the browser and added to `localStorage` but upon refresh, only the example component is shown (Box 1) and the input done by the user is lost. Any idea on what could be the issue?

```
mport React, { Fragment, useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
import { BoxList } from './components/BoxList';
import { SearchBox } from './components/SearchBox';

const KEY = "boxApp.boxes";

export function App() {
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([ {id: 1, title: 'Box 1', content: 'This is just an example of a box, remove it and create yours!' } ])
  
  const boxTitleRef = useRef();
  const boxContentRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedBoxes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEY));
    if (storedBoxes) {
      setBoxes(storedBoxes);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() =>{
    localStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(boxes));
  }, [boxes]);

  const removeBox = (id) => {
    const remainingBoxes = boxes.filter((box) => box.id !== id);
    setBoxes(remainingBoxes);
  }

  const addNewBox = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const boxTitle = boxTitleRef.current.value;
    const boxContent = boxContentRef.current.value;
    if (boxTitle === '' || boxContent === '') return;
    setBoxes( previousBoxes => {
      return ([...previousBoxes, { id: uuidv4(), title: boxTitle, content: boxContent}])
    });

    boxTitleRef.current.value = null;
    boxContentRef.current.value = null;
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SearchBox  />
      <div>
        <h2>Add a box</h2>
        <form>
         <input type='text' placeholder='Title' ref={boxTitleRef}></input>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Content' ref={boxContentRef}></input>
          <button type='submit' onClick={addNewBox}>➕</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <BoxList boxes={boxes} removeBox={removeBox}/>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to debug the lines inside `useEffect()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is coming from the below `useEffect` that you have:

```
useEffect(() =>{
   localStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(boxes));
}, [boxes]);
```

It updates the `localStorage` every time `boxes` changes, but also when the component gets mounted the first time, and at this point `boxes` is equal to that initial state given to `useState`. You could remove it, and update the `localStorage` when adding and removing items:

```
const addNewBox = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const boxTitle = boxTitleRef.current.value;
  const boxContent = boxContentRef.current.value;
  if (boxTitle === "" || boxContent === "") return;
  const newBoxes = [...boxes, { id: uuidv4(), title: boxTitle, content: boxContent }];
  setBoxes(newBoxes);
  localStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(newBoxes));
  boxTitleRef.current.value = null;
  boxContentRef.current.value = null;
};
```

```
const removeBox = (id) => {
  const remainingBoxes = boxes.filter((box) => box.id !== id);
  localStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(remainingBoxes));
  setBoxes(remainingBoxes);
};
```

You coud also change your `useState` call to this:

```
const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEY)) || [ {id: 1, title: 'Box 1', content: 'This is just an example of a box, remove it and create yours!' } ]);
```

And remove the following `useEffect` that you have:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const storedBoxes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEY));
  if (storedBoxes) {
    setBoxes(storedBoxes);
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should solve your problem if you set your initial state value conditionaly from local storage like this.

Here is the piece you need to update

```
const initialValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEY));
const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState(initialValue ? initialValue : [ {id: 1, title: 'Box 1', content: 'This is just an example of a box, remove it and create yours!' } ])
```